# Incorrect table alignment causing duplicates when reading through docx

Tags: python, parsing, visual-studio-code, ms-word, xml-parsing

I am parsing a word file in Python. One of the tables shows up with duplicate columns in the df. I think it is because the top two rows are not in the same line as the bottom rows. Here is what the table looks like in word
[image]
This is the vscode output
[image]
I have no control over how the file is created, so my option is just to clean/format it in Python after reading the tables. I'm unsure how to clean it/fix formatting. I could just replace the '\t' with '', but that would not be helpful. Can I use from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL? Here's my code of reading the tables:

```
tables = []
for table in doc.tables:

    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]

    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text

    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))

    t7 = tables[7]
```

table 7 is the table that is behaving this way.

Any guidance or help would be highly appreciated! I can add more information if needed. Thanks